# Unregistring a GTK application

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3

I am running a Gtk.Application/Gtk.Window in python3. When running by itself, it shuts down properly.

I often run in "ipython3 --gui=gtk3" and invoking the program with "%run -d xxx.py" with the appropriate breakpoints. When I now shutdown from the icon on the window or when I get an unrecoverable error and then try to restart with the "%run -d xxx.py", this is what I get in the ipython console:

> > >
> >     Failed to register: An object is already exported for the interface org.gtk.Application at /org/gtk/Application/anonymous
> >     An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
> >     <<<

Is there some place where I can manually unregister the application? (I would be even happier with documentation explaining how gnome and apps work together:). By the way, I do want the app to have a unique instance; it is unregistering that is the problem.

Is there perhaps a better way to look at the internal objects than the %run -d command  and breakpoints?

By the way, my OS is Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.

Comment: You can kill the application's process in the terminal. First use `ps aux | grep <your_app_program_name>` to get the process id. Then, use `kill -9 <process id>`. This should work.